# bad operand types for binary operator

Tags: java

работаю с Comparator, компилятор выдает ошибку: bad operand types for binary operator '-' . Поле Name - String. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем дело?

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ComparatorCity implements Comparator<City> {

    @Override
    public int compare(City o1, City o2) {
     return o1.getName()-o2.getName();

    }
}
```

Comment: Скажите, а что вы ожидаете получить, вычитая из строки строку? Возможно вы хотели сравнить их длины?

Comment: Понял к чему вы, вероятно надо так?  return (o1.getName()).compareTo(o2.getName());  нужна сортировка по имени  в Алфавитном порядке по убыванию

Comment: Да, такой вариант подойдёт

Answer (score 1):

Как отмечено выше, для строк не определена операция вычитания, поэтому данный компаратор следует переписать следующим образом (с учетом обратного порядка сортировки):

```java
public class ComparatorCity implements Comparator<City> {
    @Override
    public int compare(City o1, City o2) {
       return o2.getName().compareTo(o1.getName());
       // return o2.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o1.getName()); // без учета регистра
    }
}
```

Однако создание отдельного класса для компаратора -- уже достаточно устаревший синтаксис.

Для сортировки городов в алфавитном порядке по *убыванию* названий достаточно воспользоваться статическими методами интерфейса `Comparator`, создавая сразу экземпляр компаратора с нужной логикой:

```java
Comparator<City> byNameDesc = Comparator.comparing(City::getName, Comparator.reverseOrder());

Comparator<City> byNameDesc2 = Comparator.comparing(City::getName).reversed();
```

Для сравнения строк без учета регистра можно воспользоваться [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER):

```java
Comparator<City> byNameAnyCaseDesc = Comparator.comparing(
        City::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
    )
    .reversed();
```

---

Касаемо использования операции вычитания при сравнении, это в принципе [антипаттерн](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-compareto-why-use-comparison-vs-subtraction), так как даже при сравнении целых чисел такой способ не гарантирует корректного порядка из-за *возможных* ошибок переполнения.